# Python - Simplifying numpy array naming

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy

My head is telling me that it's much more fun to do a sensitivity analysis on some data in Python than in Excel. That's why I initially have to import a lot of data from excel. The following code works fine, but I would like to have input on how to improve it.

```
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readexcel_column(a, b, i): ## a = startpoint, b = endpoint, i = column
    list = []
    for x in range (a,b):
        list.append(sheet.cell(row=i,column=x).value)
    return list

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('mine.xlsx') ## wb stands for workbook
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('volumes grades and market')

start = 5
end = 26 

Payable_CU = readexcel_column(start, end, 32)
Payable_CU_numpy = np.array(Payable_CU)

Payable_AU = readexcel_column(start, end, 33) # dollar/ton
Payable_AU_numpy = np.array(Payable_AU)

Payable_AG = readexcel_column(start, end, 34)
Payable_AG_numpy = np.array(Payable_AG)

Payable_MO = readexcel_column(start, end, 35)
Payable_MO_numpy = np.array(Payable_MO)
```

As you can see, the code reads certain columns in an Excel sheet. Each of the columns have the same start and end place. The only difference in the last eight lines is the column nr. and a small change in the array names. Let's say I want to do this one hundred times. Could I do something simpler, so that I don't have to copy-paste and slightly modify the same two lines?

EDIT: This is what I ended up with:

```
element = ["currency_rate", "CU", "AU", "AG", "MO", "Smaeltloen", "Hg", "Laegesvaerde"]
colu = [27, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38] # column number


i = 0
while i < len(element) + 1:
    h = "Payable_"+element[i]
    vars()[h] = h = readexcel_column(start, end, colu[i])
    print(h)
    i = i+1
```

The key was to use vars()[h].

Comment: maybe storing all columns in a list and iterate over it?

Comment: Please don't use dynamic variable names. Use a regular dict instead that holds your arrays. Like `columns = {}; columns['Payable_AU'] = readexcel_column(...);` etc, and `arrays = {key+'_numpy':np.array(val) for key,val in columns.items()}`.